# Redux reducer not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Using [`redux-api-middleware`](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware) I'm encountering a problem wherein one and only one of my reducer functions is not triggering.

I would like to handle failed api requests in a similar way to how I handle the successful api requests. Yet as far as I can tell, the `SEARCH_FAILURE` FSA never gets handled, though it is treated (AFAICT) identically to the `SEARCH_SUCCESS` FSA. It does seem to be created and dispatched, based on what I see in the devtools.

I have this

```
import { CALL_API } from 'redux-api-middleware'
import { handleActions } from  'redux-actions'
const searchReducer = handleActions({

//... other handlers elided

 SEARCH_SUCCESS: (state = defaultState, action) => {
     return {
   ...state,
    search_results: ({...action.payload}),
    api: {
        requestPending: false,
        searchPending: false
    },
  }
 },

SEARCH_FAILURE:  function(state = defaultState, action) {
    console.log("Handling SEARCH_FAILURE given state, action: ", state, action)

    return {
            ...state,
            search_results: {Total: 0},
            api: {
                requestPending: false,
                error: action.payload
                },
            errors: [action.payload, ...state.errors]
        }
},
})
```

the `SEARCH_SUCCESS` FSA gets handled by `searchReducer`, but when the server gives a 400 response, the `SEARCH_FAILURE` handler never gets called--at least I don't see the log output I would expect, and the state sure doesn't end up looking right. I do see a `SEARCH_FAILURE` entry in the redux devtools panel, however.

Serving to confuse me further, here is the declaration I have at the moment for creating the RSAA

```
export function doSearch( selected_filters, page ){
let qs = SearchPage.constructQueryString(selected_filters, page)

return {
  [CALL_API]: {
  endpoint: `/api/songs/search?${qs}`,
  method: 'GET', 
  types: [
        {type: SEARCH_REQUEST},
        {type: SEARCH_SUCCESS},
        {
           type: SEARCH_FAILURE,
           payload: (action, state, res) => {
                 if (400 === res.status)
                  {
                     console.log(`${SEARCH_FAILURE} payload: `, action, state, res)
                  }
                 return res
              }
            },
         ],
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      credentials: 'include'
     }
  }
}
```

the `payload` function *is* being called and logging more or less what I'd expect. So what am I messing up here? As far as I can discern from multiple readings of the docs for `redux-api-middleware`, this setup should yield the behavior I want, but it does not. The successes succeed, but the failures fail...

Comment: try printing the value of `SEARCH_FAILURE` in your reducer file (in global scope right after defining the reducers) as well as inside your error payload function.  There's always the chance they are different values!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when I was defining one of my types with an object rather than the just the action as you're doing for SEARCH_FAILURE. I ended up fixing by updating my package.json with:

```
"redux-api-middleware": "^1.0.0-beta3",
```

I think the problem is that the docs describe the version 1.0.0 API, but when you:

```
npm install redux-api-middleware --save
```

You end up getting an earlier version of the package.